# Highcharts Drilldown fail

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I'm using highcharts maps drilldown like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-drilldown/) 
The problem is that when i drilldown, i change the DataClasses like this

```
chart.update({
    colorAxis: {
        dataClasses: [{
            to: 5000
        }, {
            from: 5000,
            to: 6000
        }, {
            from: 6000
        }]
    }
});
```

And it works perfectly and when i drillUp i have this

```
drillup: function () {
    this.setTitle(null, { text: 'General' });
    this.colorAxis[0].update({
        colorAxis: {
            dataClasses: [{
                to: 200000
            }, {
                from: 200000,
                to: 350000
            }, {
                from: 350000
            }]
        }
    });
}
```

All works perfect but when i try to drilldown again it doesn't work.
any idea to solve this problem? or how to change the data classes in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired result just by adding "False" to the redraw option of Highcharts, because it is by default set true

`update(Object options, Boolean redraw)`

I had to read the documentation. Here is the answer in the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update).

I'm using [Highcharts JS v5.0.12 (2017-05-24)](https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js).

Here is the code

```
drillup: function() {
    this.update({
        colorAxis: {
            dataClasses: [{
                to: 200000
            }, {
                from: 200000,
                to: 350000
            }, {
                from: 350000
            }]
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6679. Until it's fixed, use `v5.0.10`.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hqngy7jj/ - using Highmaps v5.0.10